# Error Mounting SFTP Folder using SSHFS on Ubuntu: fuse: unknown option `KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, sshfs

On a Ubuntu 20.04 system, I have successfully mounted a SFTP folder by running

```
sshfs -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 foo@example.com:/ ~/foo
```

However, on a Ubuntu 16.04 system, when I run the exact same command, I get the following error

> fuse: unknown option `KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? Thank you!

---

**Ubuntu 20.04 System**

```
$ sshfs --version
SSHFS version 2.10.0
FUSE library version: 2.9.9
fusermount version: 2.9.9
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.19

ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

**Ubuntu 16.04 System**

```
$ sshfs --version
SSHFS version 2.5
FUSE library version: 2.9.4
fusermount version: 2.9.4
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.19

$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Maybe we should update SSHFS v 2.5 to 2.10.0? How can we do this on Ubuntu 16.04, since `apt install sshfs` says that the installed package is the latest one available?

Comment: (mistake deleted) but still I would expect DHG14/sha1 to work by default in OpenSSH below 8.2

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Doing `ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 foo@example.com` works on Ubuntu 16.04. Is it possible that this is a bug in `sshfs` 2.5 that was fixed by `sshfs` 2.10?

Comment: On 16.04 try `ssh foo@example.com` _without_ `-o KeyAlgorithms` and if it works also try `sshfs` without that option. That's what I meant by 'work by default'

Comment: I know this question is 2 years old, but I stumbled over this by accident, and I wonder why no one noticed that there's a typo (which most probably is the cause of the error) `KexAlgorithms` vs. `KeyAlgorithms` !